# How to assign properties/methods to AngularJS services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

**i have created an angular service:**

```
app.service('myService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    var getInfo = function(){
        return  $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'X'
        });
    };
}]);
```

**and the controller doesn't recognice it:**

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {


    myService.getInfo()
    .success(function(data, status, headers) {

    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers) {

    })

}]);
```

**i get this error in the console:**

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getInfo'
```

**what do i missing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tthat should be `this.getInfo` so that `getInfo` is assigned as a method of the service.

```
app.service('myService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    this.getInfo = function(){
        return  $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'X'
        });
    };
}]);
```

Here are two generic examples of creating services with Angular: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/luqi/2/edit)**

```
app.service('myService', function() {
  // "this" is the service
  this.foo = function() {
    console.log('foo from myService1');
  };
});
```

**Using a factory:**

```
app.factory('myService2', function() {
  var myService2 = {
    foo: function() {
      console.log('foo from myService2');
    }
  };

  //what you return from a factory is the service
  return myService2;
});
```